# Virtual box has trouble opening its own .vdi images

Tags: virtualbox

for some reason Virtualbox keeps saying it has trouble opening its own .vdi images

```
exit code: 1
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Machine
Interface: 
IMachine {5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91}
```

/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

```
root@VAIO-VPCEB23FM:~# /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
bash: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory
```

What command will reset everything so I can use it again?

Answer (score 2):

Check your /etc/init.d directory to see if there's anything related to vboxdrv. Googling shows it sometimes getting renamed to vboxdrv.dpkg.bak; others report that they have /etc/init.d/virtualbox-ose and that running

```
/etc/init.d/virtualbox-ose start
```

fixed their problem.

Also, un-installing virtualbox and installing it again would most definitely solve the problem. You may as well install dkms package when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Running VirtualBox using `gksudo VirtualBox` worked for me; I'm yet to investigate why...